# ASP.NET MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a requirement which lets the user search for properties using friendly urls. I created this route

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Search", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/refno/{refno}/status/{status}/proptype/{proptype}/locality/{locality}/pricefrom/{pricefrom}/priceto/{priceto}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "Property", action = "Search", refno = "0", proptype = "ANY TYPE", status = "ANY STATUS", locality = "ANY LOCALITY", pricefrom = "0", priceto = "NO LIMIT" }
```

and the request action="/Property/Search/refno/0/status/Converted/proptype/Airspace/locality/Any locality/pricefrom/0/priceto/No limit" actually calls the route correctly.

However there is something strange. When the search form with the results is shown the javascript script tags are being ignored and therefore some dropdowns which are filled through javascript are not being filled. I am of the impression that the routing which I have created actually blocks the script tags which I have in the master page.

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser is looking for the .js files relative to the URL. Make sure your script tags are referencing your .js files with Url.Content("~/somepath/file.js").

If that isn't the problem, make sure that there is not a javascript error someplace on your page that is blocking the rest from executing.

Answer (score 0):

HI,
First of all thanks for the reply. There are no JS errors for sure sinc the JS file is being called on a user control which always works.

I just ran the website on IIS express to trace the website. It seems that the correct post is being done, but then on the results form the js files are being requested as the search post and the js file.

For example.... if I post to /search/properties/refno/5/propstatus/finished, a correct post is first made, then when the results form is being rendered a GET action is being done to /search/properties/refno/5/propstatus/finished/jquery/jquery0.5.2.min.js which is incorrect.

To give you an idea of what I am doing. This is the user control. I am only posting the form action. Right now I am posting to a static route just to test.

action="/Property/Search/refno/0/status/Converted/proptype/Airspace/locality/Any locality/pricefrom/0/priceto/No limit"  method="post">

This is the master page header js files

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery/001-jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/utils/jquery.markaf.mvc.utils.debug.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/ui/ui.search.debug.js"></script>
```

And this is the search form which the controller posts to

Search

<% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>
    
        
            
                Ref No : <%:item.RefNo %>

<%:item.Description %>

Price : **<%:item.Price.ToString("c") %>**

">Read more...

<%} %>